# POST encodeURIComponent query string Internal Server ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, validation, xmlhttprequest, query-string, encode

UPDATE: 2015-03-18 PARTIALLY RESOLVED see comments below

POSTing HTML to server, via a pure javascript (AJAX)request, NOT USING AJAX library.

Can someone tell me why this fails? even though it is encoded?

xmlhttpObj.open("POST", "apage.aspx?name1=value1&name2=%3Cd", true);

**Internal Server Error 500 - Failed to Load resource**

WIN 7, IIS7, Chrome, pure javascript [Please, no JQuery or others]
This is a javascript xmlhttpRequest open/POST/send(); async(or sync, both fail)
Have made changes to httpRuntimeValidationMode = 2.0 and pages requestValidate = false both in web.config and page directive, all FRAMEWORKs are installed all the way to 4.0

The only portion encoded is the VALUE(%3Cd) of the second name/value pair (name2=%3Cd) - ...encoding the URL portion is worse...

The special character (%3C) is the < char and the d is the first char of the div tag... POSTing HTML to the server.

If no special chars are in that value, it passes(encoded or not) 2061 chars(even though IIS is set for 4096 and those changes are reflected in the web.config)
An angle-bracket(<) alone, passes!? thus 2 chars(%3Cd) are needed to break it.

if this line is plugged in the Broswer URL bar:  (note, the C is missing)
http://localhost/sitename/apage.aspx?name1=value1&name2=%3d 
effectively skipping the javascript httpRequest, the ResponseText is: "value1="
thus, the first value succeeds, so does the 2nd as 3D is the '=' sign(nasty coincidence-lol, threw me for a loop).

%3Cd - when the C is not removed... '[lessthan]d' equals trouble(duh!).
Yellow Trace screen: A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (name2=[lessthan]d). - no mention of Error 500 on Trace page.

Why does it not cancel the validation mechanism?!
...and I thought encoding alone would be needed?!
...and why does it choke at 2061?

Keep in mind same mechanism is used without a hick-up in countless instances, sync and async... no problems as long as 'dangerous' characters are not passed. The '='(3d) example above and the 2061 SUCCESS shows this instance is no different.

I do not post willy-nilly... I will break my head 40 hours before I beg for help, I have read the entire Internet... (sniff sniff)! (t.y.)

Answer (score 0):

...not sure that is the proper or accepted way to do this, but have resolved the issue TEMPORARILY by doing a 'replace' of '<' with a 'unique 3 chars safe string' that I can decode at will... and I believe I will have to do that for other chars that will fail the process.

I would prefer a solid accepted solution.
...and the other associated questions such as queryString length also are not resolved
t.y.

Comment: 1. TurnOFF RquestValidation Temproarily (I may now figure it out due to problem 2 having been resolved
2. QueryString len:  (RESOLVED) had a web.config in inetpub/wwwroot/ where I made changes, and web.config in site rootdir/, but encountered a web.config in inetpub/ ??? have no idea how it got there... removed it... now the QueryString Length parameters kick-in.